# Make a inflation and write text in edittext simultaneously

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton, layout-inflater

Hy everybody.

I need to verify if the content of a string is null or not. If the string is != null I make a performClick in a imageButton. This click make a inflate of layout in another layout. Then I need to write text in the editText that was inflated, but I can't. Is not possible to do a inflation and write text in editText inflated simultaneously.

Here is my code

```
if(sApelido != ""){
         inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         b = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.socio_form_structured_name,null);
         lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id7);
         lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.socio_form_structured_name);
         lLayout.addView(b);




        apelido.setText(null);      //Write in one of the editText's that was inflated
    apelido.setText(sApelido);  //apelido is a editText that belongs to LinearLayout b
}
```

I don't know if you understand my question
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be more specific as to the exact problem with your code, but one possible problem is that you should be using `.equals()` to compare String values, not the `!=` operator.

Try using the following instead. I like to use

```
if (sApelido != null && !sApelido.equals(""))
{
    //your logic
}
```

Comment: Hy wsanville.I update my question. I also try this way but don't work. If I do only thge inflation only it works. But if i do the inflation and try to write in editText inflated simultaneously don't work :S

Comment: resolve the problem. I was to get the editText before the if. My code now is if(!sApelido.equals("")){ imbtMore = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.se_ivMore);  imbtMore.performClick(); apelido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sfsn_etStructuredNameApelido); apelido.setText(null);  apelido.setText(sApelido); } Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

and to write in the inflated view you could just use something like this :

```
    public View displayEditText(){
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edit_text_layout, null);
    EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.setText(sApelido)
    return v;
    }
```

then just add the View to your layout or wherever you want to display it.

Comment: Hy Slicklito. Thanks for your reply.I update my question. I also try this way but don't work. If I do only the inflation only it works. But if i do the inflation and try to write in editText inflated simultaneously don't work :S

Comment: I resolve the problem. I was to get the editText before the if. My code now is                                                               if(!sApelido.equals("")){
                        imbtMore = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.se_ivMore);             imbtMore.performClick();                                           apelido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sfsn_etStructuredNameApelido);
               apelido.setText(null);               apelido.setText(sApelido);
} Thanks for your help anyway :)